# Wordpress visual composer backend editor not showing

Tags: visual-editor, composer

I have a problem with my WordPress visual composer.

It's working in woo commerce during uploading of pictures and content but not showing in page edit. Whenever I try to edit page, it's just showing classic edit even no any option of visual composer is there in the edit page.

Comment: What do you mean classic? You probably just need to click the "html" tab at the top right.

Comment: My page edit is showing like this https://camo.githubusercontent.com/36d135d892dbef965a09d18d9fdd6b222511dd85/68747470733a2f2f636c6475702e636f6d2f48306f4b42667069646b2e706e67

Comment: I need of visual composer to edit my page but page is showing like this link: https://camo.githubusercontent.com/36d135d892dbef965a09d18d9fdd6b222511dd85/68747470733a2f2f636c6475702e636f6d2f48306f4b42667069646b2e706e67

Comment: Please help me to get back visual composer to edit my content.

Comment: Have you tried the plugin [Classic Editor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/classic-editor/)? What you see is the new "editor" in WordPress.

Comment: Fuxia, just in pages, visual composer is not showing but in products, everything is ok. Visual composer is not showing in pages

Comment: Did you update to latest version of VC?